# Accessing Windows Store Page from BackStack

Tags: mvvm, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1-universal

We have a requirement to remove items from the BackStack in our Windows Store app. We **successfully** do this by calling the Remove method

```
this.rootFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(backStackIndex)
```

However as we are using an MVVM approach I would like to tidy up the associated View and it's ViewModel. Without this tidy up we end up with an orphaned View\ViewModel.

I cannot find a way of getting an instance of the View that is associated with the PageStackEntry. Does anyone know how I could do this?